# Does the Arduino wireless shield mate with an arduino mega?

Tags: wireless, xbee, arduino

I have an arduino mega and I was wondering if this arduino xbee wireless shield (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoXbeeShield) would work with it?

I've only seen people using it with the uno..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be on the [information page for the Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560):

> The Mega2560 is designed to be compatible with most shields designed for the Uno, Diecimila or Duemilanove. Digital pins 0 to 13 (and the adjacent AREF and GND pins), analog inputs 0 to 5, the power header, and ICSP header are all in equivalent locations. Further the main UART (serial port) is located on the same pins (0 and 1), as are external interrupts 0 and 1 (pins 2 and 3 respectively). SPI is available through the ICSP header on both the Mega2560 and Duemilanove / Diecimila. *Please note that I2C is not located on the same pins on the Mega (20 and 21) as the Duemilanove / Diecimila (analog inputs 4 and 5).*

Even though the Arduino is a popular electronics development platform, your question really is about product compatibility (rather than electronics design), so you therefore need to consult the manufacturer for compatibility.

<sub>Note: There are a few kinds of Arduino Mega, I selected the Mega 2560 in the example above.</sub>